# Keyboard shortcut to expand a grouped taskbar button

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar, hotkeys

When one points cursor to a grouped taskbar button, it gets expanded displaying previews of the grouped windows. Is there any keyboard hotkey that can do the same for the active window? The purpose is to quickly navigate through the windows in a group.

I know about `Ctrl`+ mouse click, but am looking for keyboard-only solution and I want to see previews (as with `Alt` + `Tab`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Review the [windows keyboard shortcuts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts)

You may want <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>{number}</kbd> to select the taskbar or item in the taskbar,
and then up arrow to see the expansion of group.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I have missed that `Win`+`{number}` is close to what I need. The only drawback is that I need to pay attention to the position of an app on the taskbar. I suppose there is no shortcut to act on the active app directly?

Comment: You can press `Win+T` multiple times, and that will switch focus to each app in turn.

Comment: Well, that's far from quick.